# A protest to fight against racism

Tags: expressions

Is a protest intended to fight against racism an *anti-racism protest* or a *racism protest*?

I maintain that it is the latter, but am curious to know and am having trouble finding an answer with searches.

Comment: I'd say, "racism protest," since you protest "racism," not "anti racism"...

Comment: I agree! But I need scholarly support. A war protest, or an anti-war rally, but not an anti-war protest!

Comment: Please, check out this Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+war+protest%2Ca+protest+against+the+war%2Can+anti-war+protest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20war%20protest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20protest%20against%20the%20war%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It is a tricky question as the first noun in 2-noun compound nouns can state a purpose of the second noun such as "smoking room" vs. "smoking ban". The room is for smoking and the ban prohibits smoking.

Comment: @Elian If you change the search words, you get [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=war+protest%2Cprotest+against+the+war%2Cantiwar+protest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwar%20protest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprotest%20against%20the%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cantiwar%20protest%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Elian Yes, that's why I called it a tricky question. Are you in favor of a war? :-) I hope not.

Comment: Either works.  Probably "racism protest" is better, but it would depend somewhat on context.

Answer (score 2):

"Anti-racism protest" and "Racism protest" could be both synonym and antonym depending on the context. It is very unlikely people would protest in favor of racism, but we cannot be 100% certain. There are some issues we need to consider.

As I commented above, a two-noun compound is very tricky because the first noun could mean either "purpose" or "object" of the action of the second noun, especially when nouns like protest, demonstration, rally are used. You can guess what it means depending on the context, but you could never tell whether the noun before them is ***purpose or object***.

If you use "antiwar protest", it means most likely the purpose of protesting, but if you use "war protest", it is (again most likely) an object that is protested. If you look at the below Ngram Viewer, you could see all those 4 examples *antiwar protest, protest against the war, war protest, protest against war* were used during 1970's when the Vietnam War was fought.

[image]

[A protest in favor of war](http://tvnews.vanderbilt.edu/program.pl?ID=204872) is not impossible and "anti-war protest" and "war protest" could be misleading depending on context, even though it has a small chance.

We usually protest against something to which we object politically and idiollogically. Using "against" after protest will clear any chance of misleading anyone. As you can see in the below, "protest for" and "protest in favor of" are rarely used compared with "protest against".

Conclusion: We had better use "protest against X" rather than "X protest" or "anti-X protest" especially when there is a chance of misleading people.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, your observation that "protest" can be taken two different ways is critical to understanding why both of the proposed phrases are "correct".  Expecting people to change their habits and begin using "protest against", however, is folly.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, definitely. But that's how languages have evolved through many follies. I added "when there is a chance of misleading people" to make it look like less folly.